# Event Triggering in asp.net using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, class

I've created two buttons using javascript; yes and no. I need to get the event triggered when the button is clicked.

i.e... onclick=getvalue().

```
public void SetYesButton(string msg_button_class) {
    this.msgbox_Yes_button = "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Yes\" class=\"" + msg_button_class + "\" onClick=\"getvalue()\";>";
}

public void SetNoButton(string msg_button_class) {
    this.msgbox_No_button = "<input type=\"button\" value=\"No\" class=\"" + msg_button_class + "\" onClick=\"document.getElementById('pagedimmer').style.visibility = 'hidden'; document.getElementById('msgbox').style.visibility = 'hidden';\">";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand your question, but a suggestion.

Remove the penultimate semi-colon:

```
"<input type=\"button\" value=\"Yes\" class=\"" + msg_button_class + "\" onClick=\"getvalue()\">";
```